# how to prepare .amr or .wav file for yamnet.tflite model in kotlin or java

Tags: java, tensorflow, kotlin

I'm trying to prepare the input for yamnet.tflite model by using this code.
I used this code from GitHub.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream
import java.io.DataInputStream
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.ByteOrder


object AudioConverter {
    fun readAudioSimple(path: File): FloatArray {
        val input =
            BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(path))
        val buff = ByteArray(path.length().toInt())
        val dis = DataInputStream(input)
        dis.readFully(buff)
        // remove wav header at first 44 bytes
        return floatMe(shortMe(buff.sliceArray(44 until buff.size)) ?: ShortArray(0)) ?: FloatArray(
            0
        )
    }

    fun FloatArray.sliceTo(step: Int): List<FloatArray> {
        val slicedAudio = arrayListOf<FloatArray>()
        var startAt = 0
        var endAt = 15600
        val stepSize = if (step != 0) (15600 * (1f / (2 * step))).toInt() else 0
        while ((startAt + 15600) < this.size) {
            if (startAt != 0) {
                startAt = endAt - stepSize
                endAt = startAt + 15600
            }
            slicedAudio.add(this.copyOfRange(startAt, endAt))
            startAt = endAt
        }
        return slicedAudio
    }

    private fun shortMe(bytes: ByteArray): ShortArray {
        val out = ShortArray(bytes.size / 2)
        ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(out)
        return out
    }

    private fun floatMe(pcms: ShortArray): FloatArray {
        val floats = FloatArray(pcms.size)
        pcms.forEachIndexed { index, sh ->
            // float to -1,+1
            floats[index] = sh.toFloat() / 32768.0f
            // floats[index] = sh.toFloat() / 16000.0f
        }
        return floats
    }


}
```

**And use this class**

```
//input wav file
 AudioConverter.readAudioSimple(file).sliceTo(0)
                    .forEach { 
                        audioTensor.load(it)
                        classifier.classify(audioTensor)
                    }
```

But the model generates the wrong results. Please let me know how to prepare the .wav file in the right way.

please help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I have found the solution but it's not optimal but it works.

**Add these dependencies**

```
  // to run yamnet.tflite model
 implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-audio:0.2.0'
  // prepare input file for model
 implementation("com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-android")
 implementation 'com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-full:4.5'
```

**Run this code for preparing and processing input .wav or .amr file**

```
val srcFile =File("src_file_path")
// load and prepare model
val classifier = AudioClassifier.createFromFile(this, MODEL_FILE)
val audioTensor = classifier.createInputTensorAudio()
// temp file
val tempFile = File.createTempFile(System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),".wav")

  if (!tempFile.exists()) {
      tempFile.createNewFile()
            }

// make input file required input for model model
FFmpegKit.execute("-i $srcFile -ar 16000 -ac 1 -y ${tempFile.absolutePath}")

 val musicList = ArrayList<Short>()
    val dis = LittleEndianDataInputStream(FileInputStream(tempFile))
    while (true) {
        try {
            val d = dis.readShort()
            musicList.add(d)
        } catch (e: EOFException) {
            break
        }
    }
    // The input must be normalized to floats between -1 and 1.
    // To normalize it, we just need to divide all the values by 2**16 or in our 
   //code, MAX_ABS_INT16 = 32768
    val floatsForInference = FloatArray(musicList.size)
    for ((index, value) in musicList.withIndex()) {
        floatsForInference[index] = (value / 32768F)
    }

   audioTensor.load(floatsForInference)
   val output = classifier.classify(audioTensor)
```

That's it